# Sumif row values if year matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to sum all the yearly totals together from the data below:

[image: yearly totals]

I have the following formula in I16

`=SUMIFS(I3:CS3,I2:CS2, ">="&DATE(H16,1,1), I2:CS2, "<="&DATE(H16,12,31))`

Unfortunately this gives a 0 amount. I thought it was maybe something to do with the date format so I created row 1 which has the formula `=YEAR(I2)` in I1 and copied across to the right. If I change the SUMIFS to use the date range I1:CS1 I get the same result.

Is there something I should be doing with the formats to make this work or is there something fundamentally wrong with my formula?

Comment: So `=SUMIFS(I3:CS3,I$1:CS$1,H16)` does not work?

Comment: I will bet, that your values in row 3 are numbers-stored-as-text and not true numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9hJRYRsONOcFHxpSI8A?e=Y2yDBa)/screenshots refer:

Per commentary - this is likely due to number formatting in the currency / projected value field (row 3).

**Typical case**

The 'typical' case will require minimal adjustments (multiplying by 1 should suffice to convert text format to value in such cases):

```
=SUM((--$E$3#)*(1*C8=--$E$1#))
```

[image: typical]

---

Notes: modify the following ranges as req. :

- `E3#`: `E3:ER3` (projected values [£ values, row 3])
- `E1#`: `E1:ER1` (time horizon [years, row 1])

This type of 'format' discrepancy can arise in numerous ways - a common example is when values are copied from somewhere else (HTML/notepad etc.) where source values included an extra space before/after.  Another example is when Excel applies formatting (RE: delimiters etc.) from a previous/recent import within the active workbook/session.  These are easily trimmed and can be handled using double-negation (e.g. `--C3 = 1*C3` for numerical values)

However, if there was an extra space (or [empty whitespaces](https://emptycharacter.com/)) within the projected 'text' value = then more 'cleaning' may be required.

---

**Final resort**

As a thought experiment - I include a 'final-resort' case which strips any non-numerical character out of the cell (regardless of where these occur, printable or otherwise)...per-below.

This is arguably overkill - but may be of interest:

```
=--TEXTJOIN("",1,LET(x_,MID(CLEAN("'"&E3&"'"),SEQUENCE(1,LEN(CLEAN("'"&E3&"'")),1,1),1),y_,UNICODE(x_),FILTER(x_,--(y_<=57)*(y_>=48))))
```

[image: Final resort - helper]

The sumifs (typical) can then be applied to row 4 (instead of 3).

This requiresOffice 365 compatible version of Excel (modify as required RE: let & remove 'clean' function/outside wrapper for earlier veresion)

---