# Spill Sum formula in column excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets, one called **All Project Net Profit** with row data spilling across the rows with month/year dates and the Net Profit total in row 13. The following is a sample of the data:

| 2017 | 2017 | 2017 | 2017 | 2017 | 2018 | 2018 | 2018 | 2018 | 2018 | 2018 | 2018 | 2018 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aug-17 | Sep-17 | Oct-17 | Nov-17 | Dec-17 | Jan-18 | Feb-18 | Mar-18 | Apr-18 | May-18 | Jun-18 | Jul-18 | Aug-18 |
| -22596 | 77104 | 81604 | 81604 | 81604 | 81604 | 81604 | 81604 | 81604 | 81604 | 81604 | 81604 | 81604 |

The other sheet called **Yearly Net Profit** calculates the yearly Net Profit using the formula `=SUM((--TEXT('All Projects Net Profit'!$I$13#,"£0,00")*(1*A2=--'All Projects Net Profit'!$I$1#)))` pasted in to **B2**.

For now I have manually copied the formula down the columns but is there a way to make it spill for the amount of entries in Column A?

Sample data for the **Yearly Net Profit** sheet:

| Year | Net Profit |
| --- | --- |
| 2017 | 299320 |
| 2018 | 979248 |
| 2019 | 943813 |
| 2020 | -206450 |
| 2021 | -763368 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using BYROW:

```
=BYROW(  A2:A6,
 LAMBDA( x,
SUM((--TEXT('All Projects Net Profit'!$I$13#,"£0,00")*(--x=--'All Projects Net Profit'!$I$1#)))))
```

You first declare the range you want to use your formula: `A2:A6`;

Then you use LAMBDA to name that byrow-range: `x`;

Then use your "regular" formula and replace the `A2` from your original formula, that you want to do byrow with `x`.

Done.

Comment: Worked great. Adjusted to the following to restrict output to the same number of rows in column A `=BYROW(  A2#,
 LAMBDA(x,
SUM((--TEXT('All Projects Net Profit'!$I$13#,"£0,00")*(1*x=--'All Projects Net Profit'!$I$1#)))))`

Comment: May I ask why you have them as spill ranges and being text? If you fix the spill ranges to be numbers a simple SUMIF would suffice and spill the results

Comment: I was getting formatting issues with SUMIF. I asked this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75011753/sumif-row-values-if-year-matches) and used some of the resulting answer to construct the working formula

Comment: Like Scott Craner commented it was probably a formatting issue. But since you here present it as a spill range and try to convert the text to number inside this formula. Why not convert it in the formulas that create the spill of `'All Projects Net Profit'!$I$13#` and `'All Projects Net Profit'!$I$1#,` so you could simply use `=SUMIF('All Projects Net Profit'!I1#,A2#,'All Projects Net Profit'!I13#)`

Comment: I did try that but unfortunately, maybe due to the spill nature of the data in I13 it didn't work..

Comment: Maybe it's worth opening a question on that rather than this. This is unnecessary complicating things, if you ask me.